# How do I reference my own class in an Android content XML file?

Tags: xml, class, substitution

I'm using Android Studio and in my content XML file, I was referencing android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.  Instead of the ViewPager class, I want to use my own VerticalViewPager class.

How would I do that? Here is what I have now:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 android:id="@+id/pager"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Thanks,
Terry

Answer (score 0):

On the design screen for the content XML, the following was shown:

[image]

I then clicked on "**Change to**" and that fixed it.  I compiled and it executed properly.